# How can i change the default ssh rsa key used?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm using Ubuntu and I have a few keys which i'm using to connect to remote machines.
The key I created using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` is located in my home folder at `~/.ssh/` and called `rsa_id`.
I have another key which is being used by the DevOps team in my company and I want it to become the default key.
I've looked at the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and there's this line there:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```

So I was wondering about two things:

```
1. When I issue my key using the command specified above, does it copy the content of my newly created key to this file?
2. If I want to change the default key used, shall I add another `HostKey` line and point it to the DevOps key?
```

Thanks

Comment: You may be at risk of confusing the **system**'s key with the **user**'s key; the one in `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` identifies your system, not you as a user, and has nothing to do with `ssh`ing into remote systems.

Comment: I don't understand why the question has been voted down...

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I believe this is the answer to your question. I did not want to copy paste the answer.

https://superuser.com/questions/263405/how-do-we-specify-an-ssh-default-identity